# Eclipse kepler SR 2 and Websphere

Tags: eclipse, websphere

I have installed webspehere Application Server on my machine. 
I have also installed Eclipse kepler SR 2.

I want to create a websphere profile, however in Eclipse I don't see 'Websphere' under Windows->Preferences->Servers-> ?

I am not sure if I am missing any plugin?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'Eclipse kernel SR 2'

Comment: Do you mean eclipse kepler sr2 ? why using old versions ?

Comment: What WAS version do you have? Did you let Eclipse to search for different runtimes? under Server -> Runtime Environments -> Search... (and pick the path to your WAS installation)

Answer (score 2):

You need to download WebSphere Developer Tools to your Eclipse. WDT support 3 latest versions of Eclipse, so at this moment (17.10) - Mars, Neon and Oxygen, although it usually works with older also. You will need [Eclipse for Java EE developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/oxygenrc2).

The easiest way is either start from this page [Download Liberty in Eclipse](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-eclipse/) or just find WDT via Eclipse Marketplace.

If you plan to develop for traditional WebSphere you will find server tools here - [WebSphere Developer Tools for Eclipse Oxygen](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-WebSphere_Developer_Tools_for_Eclipse_Oxygen).